# Updating to Angular 8: "Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ScrollbarHelper"

Tags: angular, angular8

My code base is not that old, it was written with version 7 of Angular.

When I run

ng update @angular/cli @angular/core

all that happens is updated library references, changes to some routes, a couple of ViewChild changes, and a file called browserslist is moved.  I ran right through an upgrading list and got this error, so I started again and just ran this command and it immediately gives this error.

I have no ScrollbarHelper in my code.  I've googled and found three posts, none very helpful.  A vanilla version 7 project that is updated runs just fine.  My next step will be to import my existing code a bit at a time to find out which bit causes this error to occur.

Comment: Are you able to share some more of the console error you receive? I also had a few issues when I upgraded. I tried to do a `rm -r -f node_modules` and do `npm install` again. That fixed one project. Another project had another error, and that was because some of my Services were using arguments in the constructor that were not `@Injectable`.

Comment: Are you using ngx-datatable ? In my case removing ngx-datatable with npm and installing it again helped.

https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/issues/1693

Comment: did you already import your existing code ?, I am facing same issue and I would like to avoid if posible to downgrade everything to Angular 7

Comment: It was related to the scrollbar helper being used in a library I was using.  I had to track that down and update it

Comment: Remember to add your own answer with details of what was wrong and how you fixed it. This could be useful to other users.

Comment: @cgraus I'm not able to resolve this issue. How did you locate the library that was using Scrollbar Helper?

Answer (score 9):

In Angular 8 I changed dependencies in package.json to "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^15.0.0" then run npm install.